# Is there any free software that can open InDesign files?

Tags: gratis, vector-graphics, graphic-design

I have a flyer that another person created with InDesign. The gave me the raw InDesign files. Is there any free (as in no cost) software that I can use to open the file and edit it?

I personally use mainly Windows, but would also appreciate information about software for other platforms.

Comment: What operating system or does it not matter?

Comment: Scribus *may* have support, but I'm not sure if it ever [made it into the actual binaries](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/File_formats_that_should_be_supported_by_Scribus_%28wish_list%29).